# jQuery - Send text from input field to div with predetermined text

Tags: jquery, text, html, input, send

With preferably using jquery id want to update written text from input field into a div from a click of a button.

Also, when that happens id like that text to have a specific text around it that was predefined

"written text"

"AND THE PRE written text DEFINED TEXT"

On another note i was writing this as i got thinking... something like this post preview in stackoverflow wouldnt be bad either. Because its not important that the text will be shown after a click of a button. Of course.. which ever way would be easier.. thats the one i would go with...

Any ideas? I googled my ass off but i guess i couldnt find the right search words to describe sending text from input field to div with jquery...

I really have no starting point as far as the actual functions gom, but heres the inputs and divs at least.
http://jsfiddle.net/XrBy2/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('input[type=button]').click(
            function (){update(); }
        );

$('input.clear').click(
        function(){
            $('div.update-here').html("");
        }     
    )

    });
```

and for clear button give class clear it `<input value='clear' class='clear' />`

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var textfront = "some pre defined text";

    var textend = "some pre defined text back";

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('input[type=button]').click(
            function (){update(); }
        );

    });

    function update()
    {
        $('div.update-here').html(textfront+$('#inputform').val()+textend);
    }
```

**UPDATE** change here

```
$('div.update-here').html(textfront+$('#inputform').val()+textend);

$('div.update-here').html(textfront+$('input[name=update]').val()+textend);
</script>

<div class="update">
  <p>Update:</p>

  <input type="text" name="update" id="inputform"/>
  <input type="button" value="update"/>
</div>

<div class="update-here"></div>

<div style="margin: 0px;" class="example">written text</div>
<div class="example">AND THE PRE written DETERMINED TEXT</div>
```

Comment: @experimentX Wow... simpler than i thought really.. one thing though. Id like to be able to edit the text and update again. This apparently does that once.

http://jsfiddle.net/XrBy2/5/ also you can edit here and press update at the top thatll save it with a new url..if you want to.

Comment: @UserOfAllTheUsers well i am understanding what you mean. so you want the control of predefined text

Comment: @experimentX Lets say someone goes and writes something and then he presses update button.. with this current setup he wont be able to change his mind and write something else and update again Without refreshing in between the edits and id like the ability to do that without the refresh in between. Does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

This is the final with the added clear button and its function.

http://jsfiddle.net/XrBy2/13/

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var textfront = "front-";

    var textend = "-back";

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.update').click(
            function (){update(); }
        );
        $('.clear').click(
              function (){clear(); }
        );

    });

    function update()
    {
        $('div.update-here').html(textfront+$('.update-it input').val()+textend);
    }
    function clear()
    {
        $('div.update-here').html($(''));
    }
</script>
```

html

```
<div class="update-it">
  <p>Update:</p>
  <input type="text" name="update" /><input class="update" type="button" value="update" /><input class="clear" type="button" value="clear" />
</div>

<div class="update-here"></div>
```

and related css

```
.body { font-size: 12px;}

.update-it { border: 1px solid #e1e1e1; padding: 4px 7px 4px 4px; width: 150px; }
.update-it input { width: 100%; }

.example, .update-here { background: #f1f1f1; margin-top: 30px; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 4px 7px 4px 4px; height: 10px; line-height: 10px; }
```

Comment: is it working? sure you nailed it .. congrats .. if any help required, i will help